# Invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char [-fpermissive]

Tags: c, function

I'm new to C..so, please bear with me.. I want to call function printReceipt(char, char, char) in function calculatePrice(char), but it said that there's an error for invalid conversion from char to char at the function call for printReceipt. Can anyone please help me?

```
double calculatePrice(char cust)        //calculate total price for each customer and return the value
{
    char code[5], size, top;
    double discount, drPrice, topPrice, price;


    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the order's code :");
    scanf("%s", code);

    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter size of cup : ");
    scanf(" %c", &size);

    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter topping : ");
    scanf(" %c", &top);



    if((strcmp(code, "T1")==0) || (strcmp(code, "T2")==0) || (strcmp(code, "T3")==0) ||(strcmp(code, "T4")==0) || (strcmp(code, "T5")==0))  //drinks code
    {
        if(size == 'R')
            drPrice = 4.90;
        else if(size == 'L')
            drPrice = 5.90;
    }

    if((strcmp(code, "CH1")==0) || (strcmp(code, "CH2")==0) || (strcmp(code, "CH3")==0) || (strcmp(code, "CH4")==0) || (strcmp(code, "CH5")==0))    //drinks code
    {
        if(size == 'R')
            drPrice = 6.90;
        else if(size == 'L')
            drPrice = 7.90;
    }

    if((strcmp(code, "C2")==0) || (strcmp(code, "C3")==0) || (strcmp(code, "C5")==0))   //drinks code
        drPrice = 5.90;     

    if((strcmp(code, "S1")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S2")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S5")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S7")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S9")==0)) //drinks code
        drPrice = 6.90;

    if((strcmp(code, "S3")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S4")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S6")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S8")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S10")==0) || (strcmp(code, "S11")==0))    //drinks code
        drPrice = 5.90; 

    if(strcmp(code, "C1") == 0)     //drinks code
        drPrice = 3.90;

    if(strcmp(code, "C4") == 0)     //drinks code
        drPrice = 4.90;

    if(top == 'B' || top == 'G' || top == 'J' || top == 'P' || top == 'A')      //topping type
        topPrice = 0.60;

    if(top == 'X')      //if no topping is selected
        topPrice = 0.00;

    if(cust == 'M')     //customer type
        price = 0.8 * (topPrice + drPrice);         

    else if(cust == 'S')    //customer type
        price = 0.85 * (topPrice + drPrice);    

    else if(cust == 'R')    //customer type
        price = topPrice + drPrice; 

    printReceipt(code, size, top);

    return price; //return value
}


void printReceipt(char code, char size, char top)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("receipt.txt", "w");

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(f, "bla bla bla");


    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: code is a char [5] not a **char** as required by the function

Comment: Well, `code` isn't a `char`, it is an array of chars, which will be passed to a function as pointer to its first element, i.e. as `char *`. At the moment is isn't clear how you use `code` in `printReceipt`, but I guess you want to have `char *code` or maybe even `const char *code` as argument to that function.

Comment: Side note: With such a small char buffer for `code`, you should guard against overflowing the buffer by specifying the max number of characters when scanning: `scanf("%4s", code)`.

Comment: And learn to construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
 void printReceipt(char code, char size, char top)
```

This function expect `char` as first argument and in call you pass a `char array`-

```
  printReceipt(code, size, top);
                ^ code is char array  (declared as char code[5])
```

Either change type of first argument to `char *` in function `printReceipt` or pass a single character to it .

Make changes according to your need.

For safety write this -  `scanf("%s", code);`  like this -

```
 scanf("%4s", code);
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
void printReceipt(char code, char size, char top)
```

to

```
void printReceipt(char *code, char size, char top)
```